# Netsuite REST API Contract not automatically created with Sales Order

Tags: postman, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

When I create a new Sales Order through Postman in Netsuite using the rest api (https://{accountNumber}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder), it successfully creates the Sales Order but a contract is not being automatically created.

I tried adding different order statuses to the sales order creation, which are supposed to trigger an automatic contract creation but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely a UserEventScript or transaction work flow that triggers the contract creation. It must be deployed to run under the REST_WEBSERVICES execution context.

Comment: Thanks! I saw in the documentation that there is a setting to set the script to run from REST calls, which we were having trouble configuring so I switched to SOAP calls and now the contracts are being created properly :)